# Next.js Image Optimization Increases Filesize Instead of Decreasing it

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I have fetched uploaded images from an api that originally has file size of 208kb with resolution of 3488*2633.
I have used below code to fetch image from external api

```
const ExternalImage = forwardRef((props,ref) => {
const {src,quality,folder,...rest} = props;
const [source,setSource] = useState(`${process.env.IMAGE_DOMAIN}/${folder}/${src}`)
return (
    <Image
        src={source}
        quality={quality != undefined ? quality : 100}
        {...rest}
        onError={() => setSource(NotFound)}
    />
)
})
```

Now when I see the network tab, the same image that browser is fetching is 1 Mb. I tried to cross check if it is true, I downloaded the image that next js optimizes and found that the image file size has increased instead of decreasing.

How is this even optimizing? Am I missing anything in code?

My next.js config:

```
module.exports = {
env: {
  API_DOMAIN: 'https://api.somedomain.com/web-api/v1.0',
  IMAGE_DOMAIN: 'https://api.somedomain.com',
},
images: {
  domains: ['https://api.somedomain.com/','api.somedomain.com'],
  deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
  imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
},
}
```

Comment: Try moving the `quality` prop down a bit, something like 80 maybe.

Comment: Isn't 100 original quality measure?

Comment: Yeah but not sure how their algorithm works under the hood. Probably worth playing with that setting and see what you get.

Comment: sure will do that

Answer (score 0):

Adding key to images that came from array worked for me. I am not sure how and why it worked.